# How does an experienced developer get started with IoT

Tags: hardware

I'm an experienced developer using variety of technologies as well as real time. I want to learn how to develop for a device which is not a computer, tablet, or any of the familiar devices everybody knows about.

I noticed that global shopping sites offer IoT hardware such as 2 channel relay module, nodeMCU development board, and more hardware related to IoT. I have **no idea** what to do with or **get started**.

Assuming that I know how to code, how do I get started developing my first IoT device?

Comment: The "other" devices have a processor or microcontroller as well as a general computer, the only difference is in their performance, available memory, etc.

Comment: There seems to me a disconnect between 'experienced developer' and 'how to start' questions. Its very simple. Find an application that is relevant to you today (heating, lighting, automation) and implement it. Once there are _specific_ questions, you should get good answers here - most likely they will come from improvements or iteration on your original prototype. As posed, this question is really asking for opinions, there is no clearly right answer.

Comment: I've made an edit which tries to get to the kernel of the question, but keeping some of the original text. I suggest that OP @TheUnreal asks the second part "Does getting into IoT necessitate being a resourceful company or can an individual do it as well in this world?" as a separate question, as I think that it is still a relevant one.

Answer (score 14):

This is a very broad question, but I will try to give a few general pointers, hopefully useful to others, as well as you (so, please accept my apologies if I post things which you already know).

If you are asking about reading sensors, this is [telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telemetry) and not necessarily IoT. I have coded many projects where a standalone PC reads and displays some measurement.

If you also want to controller the attached hardware, this is [SCADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA). Again, it need not necessarily be connected to the internet.

Here's a diagram of SCADA, which gives a very good feel for the IoT in general. Note that the [PLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller)s on the diagram are sensors and controls of IoT enabled devices.

[image: SCADA architecture]

You can ask for hardware commendations for sensors & controller at [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

And, once you have some code, you can get advice for problems at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Generally, IoT for industry involves the client/server model, with the client measuring/controlling hardware devices and reporting to/receiving commands from the server. The server also generally has a database, and allows for generation of reports for management and alarms (and may instruct the remote hardware to reconfigure/shutdown based on data received).

Phew! That’s the intro out of the way. Now to get our hands dirty.

If you want to get into the nitty gritty of coding, look at [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), and understand the difference between [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol).

Fortunately, the decades have wrapped most of the trickier stuff in libraries, and you are probably best advised to read up on RESTful services.  There are numerous free online tutorials, courses and videos, depending on your language; C is a traditional embedded language, with some using C++, but of course, use whatever you know/feel comfortable with. Python is hugely popular and simple to learn, as well as being the recommended language for the Raspberry Pi.

Personally, I prefer compiled languages to interpreted, as it is easier to get the bugs out, but the choice is entirely up to you. Just make sure that it has good support for accessing peripherals over USB, Ethernet and - still extremely common in industry – serial port.

For the server side, 90%+ of the world’s server are still running on PHP. However, there is an uptake on use of NodeJS, mainly from people who code browser apps, which currently can only be done in JavaScript and don’t want to learn two languages. I don’t recommend developing browser based IoT apps, because of the restrictions on browser code accessing the file system and peripherals (although, I would mention the likes of [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), if you want to develop for smartphone).

To get started, I would recommend a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) (coding in Python or C).

[image: Raspberry Pi board]

And I *** highly*** recommend a sensor hat. [This one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014HDG74S) is just an example, but it is not expensive and  contains

- Gyroscope – angular rate sensor: +/-245/500/2000dps Accelerometer
- Linear acceleration sensor: +/-2/4/8/16 g
- Magnetometer - Magnetic Sensor: +/- 4/8/12/16
- Gauss Barometer: 260 – 1260 hPa absolute range (accuracy depends on the temperature and pressure, +/- 0.1 hPa under normal conditions)
- Temperature sensor (Temperature accurate to +/- 2 degC in the 0-65 degC range)
- Relative Humidity sensor (accurate to +/- 4.5% in the 20-80%rH range, accurate to +/- 0.5 degC in 15-40 degC range)
- 8x8 RGB LED matrix display
- Small 5 button joystick

[image: sensor board]

That will allow you gather some data and report it to your server. You might be able to find a free service online to receive and display your data. I have seen some on other S.O site, but forget where.

But, you probably want to code your own server. I would recommend PHP as programming language. For Linux, you are well provided with [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) (Linux, Apache, Mysql & PHP). For Windows, you have to install a [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29#WAMP) (Windows … etc).

You can take your pick. I have used [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) in industrial applications for over a decade. You don’t ***have*** to use Mysql, Sqlite can serve just as well (shaless plug for my own S.O question of 6 years ago, “[**Sqlite or MySql? How to decide?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813890/sqlite-or-mysql-how-to-decide)“). You will also have to learn about [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

Based on the data received from the client/sensor, you might want to send a command back, even just a simple (display : "temperature too high", which might translate to closing a valve in an industrial system).

You might want to raise alarms in real time (send email saying that the temperature is too high).

And, you might also want to think about generating reports. Start with a table showing data  received. The consider a chart, or something fancier. Add an option to export to [Comma Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (CSV) which allows the end user to import the data into a spreadsheet for further analysis and manipulation.

If you ***do*** decide that you want fancy reporting, you ***can*** do it in PHP, but, after a few decades of that I have now moved to doing much of the report stuff client side, in the browser.

For generally principles, get an overview of  [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)s and [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). I, personally, did a lot of research and chose Google’s [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) as my programming language (there are lots of [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp) & great support), but you are free to use plain JS, Jquery, etc, as you please.

If you do decide to code browser stuff too, and you might be as well to use [NodeJs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) on the server side, so that you only have to learn one new programing language.

Too many choices? Sorry :-(

I hope that this has given you some advice, but feel free to ask questions, and let me know if there is any general advice missing here.

Comment: Thanks Mawg, most of what you said I already know and wasn't a pert of the question, I am working with PHP and Javascript as well as corodva for years. I think I will start buying UNO R3 and see how I can proceed from there.

Comment: I started writing & just couldn't stop :-)  I hope that it will help others. I don't know Cordova well enough. It's good for accessing 'phone hardware, lime camera, SIM, tilt sensor, but can it access serial port? Because that is used ***a lot*** in industry; you can get by with USB to serial convertor, which is what we use for laptops, but can Cordova send data across USB? And Ethernet?    continued ...

Comment: ... You know JS, but I wouldn't recommend using it on en embedded processor. You *can*, but it’s certainly not normal. Maybe time to pick up some Python, or C? Or, maybe you mean UNO R3 <--> server <--> browser? Stick with Arduino if you already know it, by all means. I switch to R Pi, but that’s just my personal preference. . Do you have a learning project in mind? Hint, hint … http://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/675/extreme-modification-suggestions-for-a-wi-fi-enabled-hairbrush  :-)

Answer (score 9):

As an experienced developer you have the ability to understand logic, read and write code, figure things out, and some other important skills. What you probably don't have is an understanding of basic electronics and the art of getting code from your desktop running on a small device.

Jumping in at the wrong level of complexity can be daunting, and may mean that you give up too soon. For example, people recommend the ESP8266 and NodeMCU without thinking that you need to get the right one, you need the chip mounted on a development board, you have to get your software on it, you need to wire it up to something, and only then are you able to run JavaScript. That is a lot of different skills that you need, and you could give up on any one of those stages.

My recommendation is to start with an Arduino. Where Arduino made a difference in the maker community was how easy it is to plug an Arduino in a USB port, and the compile, build, deploy chain is all sorted for you. You can write some code, and flash some LEDs very quickly.

I also suggest that you start with the official [Arduino starter kit](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoStarterKit). While it is very simple, the instructions are easy and you get a bunch of useful electronic bits and pieces (breadboard, jumper wires, LEDs, etc) that remain useful.

Don't be put off by how basic the Arduino is. Get some enthusiasm going first for the electronics and hands-on part before trying anything too complex. If you find the electronics interesting and want to do more, stick with the Arduino and get a more complex kit. I bought the [BOE Shield-Bot robot](http://learn.parallax.com/tutorials/robot/shield-bot/robotics-board-education-shield-arduino). It may not be the best or cheapest robot, but has a really good tutorial that goes into detail on how to controls servos and such. You also land up with a whole lot more useful bits.

If you get through that, you'll either give up and get back to server-side software, or you will buy more bits, soldering irons, more boards and components. Very soon you'll land up with a drawer of broken dreams like the rest of us.

I wouldn't recommend using the Pi too soon. It's more of a computer than a thing, and doesn't have important features that are necessary in the beginning of your journey of understanding (like analogue input). You'll very quickly outgrow the Arduino (it doesn't connect to the Internet very easily), but it's a good place to see whether this will be something that you enjoy.

Answer (score 6):

I will proceed to answer your first question.

If you want to just learn I can recommend you some books about IoT but I guess you can search them by yourself. If that is clear, then I would recommend you to start working on your own small project, that is how you learn the best, facing real-life problems.

You will need to decide what is what you want to create.
Here are some inspiration and cool ideas to start off:

[Arduino Projects](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Projects/) -> Microcontroller

[Raspberry Pi projects](https://diyhacking.com/best-raspberry-pi-iot-project/) -> Microprocessor (more powerful)

[hackaday.com](http://hackaday.com) -> Mixed components

Once you have the idea of what you want to do, then you need to come up with requirements for your project. The microcontroller, sensors, actuators, communication protocols, etc.

As you can see the most popular devices are [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/), [Raspberrypi](https://www.raspberrypi.org) and all the other relatives, [beaglebone black](https://beagleboard.org/black), [onion](https://onion.io/) , etc,
There are many more, the differences are the price, the compatibility with other sensors and the popularity. The popular ones are more compatible and have more support on forums.

We cam help you out with the requirement based on your project. 
Good luck!

Comment: I already have an idea, but I want to experience this world before jumping into this. I think I will start buying Uno R3 and post questions as soon as I go.

Comment: An Arduino Uno is good for controlling physical items, but it's expensive to adapt to network protocols, since you basically have to add another better microcontroller or computer to do so.  Sometimes you can find one part that does both, other times you have a network facing system that delegates the electrical control task to something like an Arduino

Answer (score 2):

Others have focused on the first facet of your question; I'm going to focus on the latter.  You asked if just anyone can get into IoT or if you have to be a big company with many resources.

If you browse the [smart-home](/questions/tagged/smart-home) tag, you'll see that there are IoT devices that have all the server side done for you already.  There are plenty of IoT devices that "just anyone" can buy, included would be the Nest cam, thermostat, etc., the Amazon Echo, the Google Home, smart ovens, refrigerators, etc.

Even many new cars qualify as objects to be sensed or controlled remotely... though perhaps not the controlled part just yet.  :)

This leads to the answer of your first question:

> How I can get started practising develop my first IoT device?

You don't necessarily have to start by developing: you can start with something simpler.  If you want to get into the developing side of it, you *could* simply take the plunge, as some have suggested, but you do have the option available to you to start simple and move gradually into the realm of the more complex.

Comment: And where better to start than http://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/675/extreme-modification-suggestions-for-a-wi-fi-enabled-hairbrush ?